# What is the definition of "She'at Hadchak" regarding mincha and ma'ariv?

Tags: zemanim, minyan, maariv, mincha-afternoon-prayer

[This M.Y. answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71179/5275) discusses the various opinions of whether one can daven Mincha and follow it with Ma'ariv immediately afterwards when one began mincha after *plag*. (Note that this wasn't the subject of my question, itself, there.)

Part of the answer cites O.C. 233:1

> הגה: וּלְדִידָן בִּמְדִינוֹת אֵלּוּ שֶׁנּוֹהֲגִין לְהִתְפַּלֵּל
>   עַרְבִית מִפְּלַג הַמִּנְחָה, אֵין לוֹ לְהִתְפַּלֵּל מִנְחָה אַחַר
>   כָּךְ; וּבְדִיעֲבַד אוֹ בִּשְׁעַת הַדַּחַק, יָצָא אִם מִתְפַּלֵּל
>   מִנְחָה עַד הַלַּיְלָה, דְּהַיְנוּ צֵאת הַכּוֹכָבִים (בֵּית יוֹסֵף
>   בְּשֵׁם אֹהֶל מוֹעֵד וְרַשְׁבָּ''א).

It says that in "emergency situations" if one davened Mincha after plag, and followed it immediately with Ma'ariv before *tzet hokachavim*, this is fine.

Would this scenario be considered "She'at Hadhcak"?

In my shul, we have trouble getting a minyan (sound all too familiar?) We prefer to daven Mincha before plag and follow it with Ma'ariv (an opinion expressed as "common practice" in O.C. paragraph mentioned). But often, we have 7 people, and the Gabbai calls or "what's-apps" (is that really a valid verb??) people to come to shul to help form the minyan. By the time we get the minyan, it is after *plag*, so we're following the other opinion that allows davening *mincha* after plag is over until night time.

Generally, in such cases, according to O.C., when one davens *mincha* after plag, he must wait until the stars emerge before davening Ma'ariv. However, those that came early will defect and leave the shul because the late-comers made them wait, unnecessarily.

In short, would not having a minyan for Ma'ariv qualify under the condition of *She'at Hadchak*, or would everyone be forced to wait until the stars emerge?

Comment: How is this different from "My Shul Davens both Mincha and Maariv between Plag and sunset. Should I daven both with them or one alone?"

Comment: @DoubleAA it is the same idea. Has that 2nd question been asked on MY?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's definitely been discussed in Poskim.

Answer (score 2):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch ([70:1](http://toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0069_L2)) writes that the custom is to *daven Ma'ariv* immediately following *Mincha*, because it would be a burden to gather a *Minyan* again.

Comment: So does it qualify as Shaat HaDechak? Many people are accustomed to doing things Bedieved out of laziness all the time.

Comment: @DoubleAA He says "נוהגין", and doesn't write against it. So yes, it does qualify.

Comment: I'm not convinced...

Comment: @DoubleAA It's right before shabbos so I can't look into it now, but Bl"N after shabbos I will. I'm pretty sure I've seen it more explicitly somewhere.

Comment: @DoubleAA There's a nuance here that you see that I don't. I'm understanding "...because it would be a burden to gather a Minyan again" as a sufficient reason why a minyan can follow Ma'ariv after mincha after plag without waiting. It might not fit the definition of *She'at Hadchak*, per se, but it seems to fit the definition of *torach tzibbur*.